# Loop through PowerPoint deck, insert photos based on hyperlink in slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint, do-loops

I have a powerpoint where each sheet contains the hyperlink to a photo. I would like to insert the image into each slide based on that file path. Is there a VBA program that would accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe not, but you can write one.

Comment: To expand on Tim's point a bit:  StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service and requests for software recommendations are frowned on.  If you decide to have a go at writing some VBA to do the job but run into problems, post the code here, describe the problem/error message/whatever and people will help.